Is $(n!^{-d})_{n\geq 0}$ a Pólya frequency sequence?
Fix a positive integer $d$. Is the sequence $(n!^{-d})_{n\geq 0}$ a
Pólya frequency (PF) sequence?  Equivalently, is the Toeplitz matrix
$A=[a_{ij}]_{i,j\geq 0}$, where $a_{ij}=0$ if $i>j$ and
$a_{ij}=(j-i)!^{-d}$ if $i\leq j$, totally nonnegative (all minors
are nonnegative)? Another equivalent condition is that we can write
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{z^n}{n!^d} = e^{cz}\prod_{j\geq
    1}\left(1+\frac{z}{\alpha_j}\right), $$
where $c\geq 0$ and the $\alpha_j$'s are positive real numbers
satisfying $\sum \alpha_j^{-1} <\infty$. The answer is "yes" for
$d=1$ (clearly) and $d=2$ (by known properties of Bessel functions).
However, the pointwise product of PF sequences need not be PF,
so something more is needed. Presumably this is a known result (if true)
from complex analysis and/or total positivity, but I'm unable to find a
reference.

I do not think this is a PF sequence even for $d = 2$. PF sequences are convolutions of geometric and Poissonian sequences, so they cannot go to zero faster than $\lambda^n/n!$ for some $\lambda > 0$. Your sequence decays too fast if $d \ge 2$. Does that make sense?

@MateuszKwaśnicki:  the Bessel function $J_0(z)$ has the Weierstrass product $\prod_{m\geq 1}\left( 1-\frac{z^2}{j_{0,m}^2}\right)$ (e.g., https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0692, page 3). Now $J_0(2i\sqrt{z})=\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{z^n}{n!^2} = \prod_{m\geq 1}\left( 1+\frac{4z}{j_{0,m}^2}\right)$. Hence $1/n!^2$ is a PF sequence.

Ah, right. What I wrote works nicely for PF functions, for PF sequences there can be additional Bernoulli factors in the convolution representation. Sorry!

This turned out to be much harder than I initially expected! I think I have a solution, see the answer below. Interestingly, the sequence $(n!)^{-d}$ is, after normalisation, the probability mass function of the Conway–Maxwell–Poisson distribution, with one of the parameters set to $1$, a fact that I was not aware of until today. Is this how your question originated?

@MateuszKwaśnicki: I had never heard of this distribution. My motivation was connected with showing that some combinatorially defined symmetric functions were e-positive (a polynomial in the elementary symmetric functions with nonnegative coefficients).

The answer is yes, the sequence $(n!)^{-d}$ is a Pólya frequency sequence for every $d \geqslant 1$.
The case $d = 1$ is straightforward, so we suppose that $d \geqslant 2$ and denote
$$ F(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(n!)^d} . $$
Then $F$ is clearly an entire function of order
$$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{n \log n}{\log (n!)^d} = \frac1d < 1 , $$
and so $F$ has genus $0$. By Hadamard's theorem, $F$ has a Weierstrass product representation
$$ F(z) = \prod_{w : F(w) = 0} \biggl(1 - \frac{z}{w}\biggr) $$
(note that $F(0) = 1$). Thus, $(n!)^{-d}$ is a Pólya frequency sequence if and only if all zeroes of $F$ are real and negative.
The latter condition is indeed satisfied. By the definition of the hypergeometric series,
$$ \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(n!)^d} = {_0F_{d-1}}(1, \ldots, 1; z) , $$
and it is known that ${_0F_q}(b_1, \ldots, b_q; z)$ has all zeroes real and negative whenever $b_1, \ldots, b_q > 0$. Einar Hille states this theorem on page 51 in:

E. Hille, “Note on some hypergeometric series of higher order.” J. London Math. Soc. 4 (1929), pp. 50–54, DOI:10.1112/jlms/s1-4.1.50

and attributes it to Adolf Hurwitz, with reference:

A. Hurwitz, “Über die Wurzeln einiger transcendenten Gleichungen,” Festschrift, herausgegeben von der Mathematischen Gesellschaft in Hamburg anlässlich ihres 200 jährigen Jubelrestes, 1890, Zweiter Teil, pp. 25–31 (30), (also Vol. 2 of the Mitteilungen of the same
Society).

This reference is accompanied by the following comments: “This paper is chiefly known through the incorrect abstract in Jahrbuch ü. d. Fortschritte d. Math.” and ”It appeared in a publication very little known, and it has unfortunately been almost forgotten ever since.” Hille additionally mentions that a proof is also given in his another paper, using Pólya–Schur's theorem on multipliers from

G. Pólya, J. Schur, “Über zwei Arten von Faktorenfolgen in der Theorie der algebraischen Gleichungen”, J. Reine Angewandte Math, 144 (1914), pp. 89–113, EuDML:149419.

[The last sentence has been edited following Christian Elsholtz's comment. I do not know which Hille's paper contains the proof, but with Pólya–Schur's result at hand, the proof is fairly straightforward. Indeed, $(n!)^{-1}$ is a multiplier sequence, and so also $(n!)^{-d}$ is a multiplier sequence. On the other hand, generating functions of multiplier sequences are in the Laguerre–Pólya class, so in particular they only have real zeros, all of the same sign.]

The name of the journal (above) is not quite right: Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik (1914),    Volume: 144, page 89-113.
Über zwei Arten von Faktorenfolgen in der Theorie der algebraischen Gleichungen. G. Pólya; J. Schur
https://eudml.org/doc/149419

@ChristianElsholtz: Ah, I see, so this was meant to refer to Pólya–Schur paper, not another Hurwitz's paper. Thanks, I will update the answer momentarily.
